# Sign In Loop with Mac In-app Purchase on Revenuecat

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, revenuecat

*I'm using RevenueCat 3.0.2*

I have a Mac app that has an entitlement with an associated product (I don't use offerings because I only sell a single thing: a license to use my app).

*Entitlement:* `azzamac`

*Product:* `azzamac`

When I click **Buy** in my app, I run this code:

```
Purchases.shared.products(["azzamac"]){ products in

  guard let product = products.first else { return }

  //Valid product here. Continuing on...

  Purchases.shared.purchaseProduct(product){ transaction, purchaserInfo, error, cancelled in
    //This function never finishes 
  }
```

I see the App Store authentication popover over and over and over and the `purchaseProduct` method never finishes. I've tried entering multiple different sandbox tester Apple IDs and nothing happens (and I know the passwords are right because the authentication box tells me when it's wrong).

[image]

Here are my debug logs from RevenueCat:

```
[Purchases] - DEBUG: Requesting products with identifiers: {(
    azzamac
)}
[Purchases] - DEBUG: Products request finished
[Purchases] - DEBUG: Valid Products:
[Purchases] - DEBUG: azzamac - <SKProduct: 0x60000001de50>
[Purchases] - DEBUG: Invalid Product Identifiers - (
)
[Purchases] - DEBUG: 1 completion handlers waiting on products
[Purchases] - DEBUG: makePurchase
[Purchases] - DEBUG: makePurchase - azzamac
[Purchases] - DEBUG: PaymentQueue updatedTransaction: azzamac (null) ((null)) (null) - 0
[Purchases] - DEBUG: PaymentQueue updatedTransaction: azzamac (null) ((null)) (null) - 0
```

Any idea why I can't get `purchaseProduct` to finish?

Comment: From the debug looks like makePurchase may be firing twice? Can you put a breakpoint there to confirm? Also, you may want to break out the .products() and .purchaseProduct() calls into separate methods. Usually the .products() completion is used to set up the 'Buy' button, then pressing the 'Buy' button triggers .purchaseProduct().

Comment: Hmm... that was a good catch. I tried loading the product separately (on `viewDidLoad`) so it was ready before the user clicks "Buy", but the same issue occurs and the log looks the same.

Comment: Do you ever get the "You're all set" modal from Apple or do the purchases appear in RevenueCat? The debug logs make it look like two purchases are being initiated somehow.

Comment: No, neither. Only the "sign in" popup shows, and RevenueCat doesn't log any purchases. Though interestingly, the "View Sandbox Data" option in RevenueCat is disabled for this app. I wonder if that's due to the absence of purchases or if I have a configuration problem.

Comment: Does a breakpoint at `Purchases.shared.purchaseProduct` get hit more than once? If you don't get the "You're all set" popup then things could be hanging up with Apple between initiating the purchase and it completing.

Comment: A breakpoint inside `Purchases.shared.purchaseProduct` never gets called (unless I hit **Cancel** in the "sign in" popup). 

Comment: The completion block won't return until there is some response from Apple, so I guess the cancellation is firing. Weird, like it's getting hung up mid purchase. Does `Purchases.shared.purchaseProduct` itself only get called once?

Comment: Yes, it gets called only once. After further troubleshooting, the same code works fine on iOS. Only macOS has this issue.

Comment: Interesting, starting to feel like maybe something with the sandbox account. Apple isn't returning a success of failure it's just "stuck". Have you tried testing with a new sandbox user?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with multiple sandbox users, including a newly created one. I'll have to keep digging into that.